# Curator lock path name containing only '0' character(s)

Tags: validation, path, apache-curator

I am new to ZooKeeper, but while helping a coworker debugging a production issue, we had found something rather unexpected. The existing code in our system uses Curator InterProcessMutex. The app creates the lock with path, say, `/TEST/ABC`. Then another part of the code creates more locks with path like `/TEST/ABC/[some integer]` while the integers are some object IDs that are entered through a UI. This has been working for a few months, until lately it suddenly stopped working.

We took a thread dump and found that the thread is blocked at trying to acquire a lock with path `TEST/ABC` and it turns out this happens whenever the path `/TEST/ABC/0000` is created (the number of 0s does not matter, as long as it only contains zeroes). Apparently some tester one day decided to enter some bogus IDs into the system which brought the system to a halt. We have fixed this, but I am curious if anyone can shed some light on why this is the case?

**Question:** why is locking `TEST/ABC/0000` the same as locking `TEST/ABC`?
*(Number of zeroes does not actually matter, anything maps to `TEST/ABC`.)*

Answer (score 0):

There is a Curator Tech Note on this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN7

Any path given to a Curator recipe is owned by that recipe. Do not use it for other things.

(NOTE: I'm the main author of Curator).